# document.elementFromPoint not precise

Tags: javascript

I defined a function in JS:

```
function getElementIDAtPoint(x,y) {

   console.log("Touch Down ("+x+", "+y+")");

   var id = '';
   var element  = document.elementFromPoint(x,y)

   while(!element.id && element.tagName != 'BODY'){
       element = element.parentElement;
       alert('tagname: ' + element.tagName + ' id: ' + element.id)
   }

   return id;
}
```

Sometimes i don't get an id, even though the element i clicked on has an id. The elements are small and maybe that's causing the issue. How can i make this more precise? i'm not a js expert

Comment: may be this demepnd on wrong x,y values you put ? Eg. when you scroll page down you shoud take that shift into account when calculate x,y values (based on mouse position) - ?

Comment: the coordinates are correct. This is actually executed in a webview on Android. I pass the touch coordinates in the function. If i scroll and i click a few times, sometimes i get the id and sometimes i don't

Comment: you use Touch - this is sometimes not precise (low sensitivity for some devices )

Comment: so there's no way to improve this?

Comment: I don't know. However I have some idea to more often call "getElementIDAtPoint" and return last found value in case when you not find ID for current x,y - you can also "save" last element (or elements) with last x and y - and check how close new x,y are that last position... (in case when you not found ID).

Comment: some kind of caching. Doesn't seem like anything i can work with since the html files are pretty huge. But thanks for trying to help